# In video editor using blender how can I smooth out corners on a box?

Tags: text-object

I want to round off the corners of my box in Blender Video Editor but can't find any information on how to do it. Now the edges are pointed and I don't want that

Does anyone know how to do it nicely?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know you can't Your best bet in Blender is probably to make them as actual objects in a 3D scene, render them to video then overlay using the video editor.

Comment: I don't know the VSE but it sounds as if you want to add a vignette to your video. There's a YT video on how to do it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg9tDBf_Q8M) although it's for Blender 2.82 so may be outdated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a plane, go to edit mode, CTRL-SHIFT-B -> Move mouse, then scroll wheel

[image]

Then press 7 to go to top view, press CTRL-SHIFT 0 to set camera to top view and add a text and move that up a little bit on z axis. Give both material (i gave emission, strength 1 and deleted all lights). Set render properties -> film -> check transparent

Then create another scene with video editing, add your movie strip. Then Shift-A -> scene -> choose your scene with the text and use alpha over as blend mode.

example:

[image]

[image]